# Prove exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that $f''(c)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$y=f(x)$ has one intersection with the straight line that passes thorugh $(0,f(0))$ and $(1,f(1))$ at $(x_0,f(x_0))$, where $0<x_0<1$,
Where $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and twice differentiable on $(0,1)$，
Prove exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that $f''(c)=0$.

since it involved the line $y=x$, I thought of let $g(x)=f(x)-x$, but this gets me nowhere-- can it be proved by contradiction? suppose there does not exist $f''(c)=0$ then by Darboux $f'$ is strictly monotonic-- I don't know how to continue next! Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: False. If $f(x)=\frac {x^{2}} 2$ then $f(x)=x$ exactly at one point of $[0,1]$,  namely $0$, but $f''(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: edited, thanks!

Comment: Even if you assume $c \in (0,1)$, it's still false. You can take $f(x) = x^2 + 1/4$. Then it intersects $y=x$ at $c=1/2$, but $f''(x) = 2$ for all $x$.

Comment: edited yet again, thanks!

Comment: For what its worth, if I was attacking this problem, I would take a preliminary step **before** even considering whether the conjecture is true.  I would ask myself, in general, how do I determine whether, given a function $g(x)$, there exists a value $x_0$ such that $g'(x_0) = 0.$  This means, I am asking whether there is a value $x_0$ such that $g(x)$ stops either increasing or decreasing at $x_0.$.  Then I would try to **stretch my intuition** by transplanting consideration of $g(x)$ onto consideration of $f'(x).$ ...see next comment

Comment: This means that I am asking whether there is a value $x_0$ such that the slope of $f(x)$, as represented by $f'(x)$ stops either increasing or decreasing at the value $x = x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

As $(x_0,f(x_0))$ belongs to the line through $(0,f(0)),(1,f(1))$; we have that the slope of this line
$$= \frac{f(x_0)-f(0)}{x_0-0} = \frac{f(1)-f(x_0)}{1-x_0} = k \text{ (say)}$$
So, by Lagrange's MVT, $\exists\; c_1\in (0,x_0), c_2\in (x_0,1) \text{ s.t. } f'(c_1)=f'(c_2)=k$

$\therefore$ By Lagrange's MVT again, $\exists\; c\in (c_1,c_2)\subseteq (0,1) \text{ s.t. } f''(c) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $g : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$g(x)=f(x)-(f(1)-f(0))x -f(0)$$ By hypothesis, $$g(0)=g(x_0)=g(1)=0$$

Because $g$ is differentiable, you can apply Rolle's theorem : there exists $y_0 \in (0,x_0)$ such that $g'(y_0)=0$, and $y_1 \in (x_0,1)$ such that $g'(y_1)=0$. And again by Rolle's theorem, there exists $c \in (y_0, y_1)$ such that $g''(c)=0$. But $g''=f''$, so you have $f''(c)=0$.